# measure() may not be called multiple times on the same Measurable

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-paging-3

I am creating an app that uses Flickr api to fetch images page by page using Pager 3 library and show it on the screen using Jetpack Compose. All works fine until it will load 4-5 pages (looks like it is floating).

I receive an error:

```
Process: com.peterstaranchuk.flickrclient, PID: 9843
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: measure() may not be called multiple times on the same Measurable
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.remeasure-BRTryo0(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:86)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.remeasure-_Sx5XlM$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:1236)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.remeasure-_Sx5XlM$ui_release$default(LayoutNode.kt:1232)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.doRemeasure-0kLqBqw(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:171)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.access$doRemeasure-0kLqBqw(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:38)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.measureAndLayout(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:207)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onMeasure(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:547)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
```

it not points to some place on my code and it's looks like it is related with the Jetpack compose measurement.

I checked all available info and didn't find an answer. May be someone has the same problem? Would be very appreciate for any clue.

My view model:

```kotlin
class SearchViewModel(
    private val interactor: SearchInteractor,
    private val photosPresentationMapper: PhotoPresentationMapper,
    eventSender: ScreenEventSender<SearchContract.Event>,
    dispatchers: DispatchersProvider
) : BaseViewModel<SearchContract.Event>(eventSender, dispatchers) {

    fun observePhotos(): Flow<PagingData<PhotoPresentation>> {
        return interactor.getPagedPhotos("nature")
            .flowOn(dispatchers.io)
            .catch { /*todo handle error state */
                Log.d("", it.message.toString())
            }
            .map {
                it.map {
                    photosPresentationMapper.map(it)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Screen composable:

```kotlin
@Composable
    fun ScreenContent() {
        val lazyPhotoItems: LazyPagingItems<PhotoPresentation> = vm.observePhotos().collectAsLazyPagingItems()

        Column {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .wrapContentSize(Alignment.Center)
                    .background(Color(ContextCompat.getColor(LocalContext.current, R.color.black60transparency)))
                    .padding(8.dp)
            ) {
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .wrapContentSize()
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(50))
                        .background(colorResource(id = R.color.search_field_background_color)),
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_search_image),
                        contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.search_screen_magnifier_icon_content_description),
                        tint = Color.White
                    )
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 8.dp, bottom = 8.dp, start = 4.dp),
                        text = stringResource(R.string.search_screen_search_field_text),
                        fontSize = 12.sp,

                        color = colorResource(id = R.color.search_field_text_color),
                        fontFamily = getFont(R.font.nunito_sans_extra_bold)
                    )
                }
            }

            LazyColumn (content = {
                items(lazyPhotoItems.itemCount, {
                    lazyPhotoItems[it]!!.id
                }) { index ->
                    ImageItem(lazyPhotoItems[index]!!)
                }
            }, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize())
        }
    }
```

I use:

```
//paging
    implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime:$paging_version"
    implementation "androidx.paging:paging-compose:$paging_compose_version"
```

with the versions:

```
    compose_version = '1.0.1'
    paging_compose_version = "1.0.0-alpha12"
```

Comment: This doesn't looks like paging problem. Try replacing your data with static content + updating it from `LaunchedEffect`. If problem still reproduces, please add it here so it can be reproduced by others

Comment: Did you find solution? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to add `.cachedIn(viewModelScope)`
Look at comment `// Here`

```
fun observePhotos(): Flow<PagingData<PhotoPresentation>> {
            return interactor.getPagedPhotos("nature")
                .cachedIn(viewModelScope) // Here
                .flowOn(dispatchers.io)
                .catch { /*todo handle error state */
                    Log.d("", it.message.toString())
                }
                .map {
                    it.map {
                        photosPresentationMapper.map(it)
                    }
                }
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. 
Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please edit your answer and explain 
how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same error and it seems like it is related with [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/208675143) bug.

So fix was just to update jetpack compose to `1.1.0-rc01` version